# keinen Waffenschein oder eine Waffenbesitzkarte - a typo?

Tags: usage, typo

I read currently a book by Nele Neuhaus and there is a sentence:

> Und der Besitz aller anderen Waffen ist ebenfalls strafbar, wenn man
> keinen Waffenschein oder eine Waffenbesitzkarte hat.

I'm not sure if it is a typo or it can be really so used - this "keinen" that comes first allows "eine" after "oder"? Or do I understand "Waffenbesitzkarte" wrong?
EDIT
This sentence the policeman says before the abovementioned:

> Der Besitz von Handgranaten und Panzerfäusten fällt unter das
> Kriegswaffenkontrollgesetz.

Comment: It could be that before this quote there's a list of weapons that you are allowed to have when you have a Waffenbesitzkarte, but then you'd say "oder nur eine Waffenbesitzkarte hat." Can you give more context?

Comment: @Raketenolli added the sentence which comes before the one I ask the question

Comment: Note that you need *both* of these licences to legally own guns in Germany - one to testify that your character is suitable in the first place, and a specific documentation for each individual firearm that you actually have.

Comment: Indeed. Insofar the statement as quoted is legally not quite correct. But policemen aren't lawyers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a not uncommon way to get around the problem that "Waffenschein" and "Waffenbesitzkarte" have different grammatical gender.
What she wanted to say was:

```
keinen Waffenschein oder Waffenbesitzkarte
```

but then the accord between "keinen" and "Waffenbesitzkarte" would be wrong.
In the non-negated case it would be quite correct to just repeat the indefinite article:

```
einen Waffenschein oder eine Waffenbesitzkarte
```

In the negated form you would then also have to switch from "oder" to "und" in order to maintain the logic, giving:

```
keinen Waffenschein und keine Waffenbesitzkarte
```

But that feels like a double negation (although it isn't) which some speakers find awkward.
To avoid that they just pay reference to the gender difference by inserting the feminine "eine" and everybody (at least every native speaker) understands that the negation contained in "keinen" extends to that.

Comment: Your answer brought me to google "keinen * oder eine", and now I see some more examples of this type. Well, it's surprising.

Comment: Neben dem Geschlecht spielt, wie von Kilian Foth angemerkt, eine Rolle, dass man einen Waffenschein und mehrere Waffenbesitzkarten haben muss, nicht entweder/oder.

Comment: Deshalb ist der zitierte Satz sachlich falsch. Seine sprachliche Struktur ist aber trotzdem wie beschrieben.

Answer (score 4):

The grammatical structure is a little ambiguous, in fact. First, the sentence means as much as this:

> And ownership of all other weapons is also illegal, unless you have a Waffenschein or Waffenbesitzkarte.

Both *Waffenschein* and *Waffenbesitzkarte* are legal German terms, referring to different licenses that allow you to own certain weapons.

The tricky part is that the negation in *kein* is extended over the whole group. The logical structure that is communicated could be illustrated like this:

> nicht [einen Waffenschein oder eine Waffenbesitzkarte]

Analysing this sentence strictly logical is confusing the speaker's intention, since it would make you structure the sentence like this instead:

> [keinen Waffenschein] oder [eine Waffenbesitzkarte]

The logically correct sentence that corresponds to the speaker's intention would actually have to read:

> wenn man keinen Waffenschein und keine Waffenbesitzkarte hat.
> [When you have no Waffenschein and no Waffenbesitzkarte].

or

> wenn man weder einen Waffenschein noch eine Waffenbesitzkarte hat.
> [When you have neither a Waffenschein nor a Waffenbesitzkarte.]

Nonetheless this is very common. It could be explained by means of [pragmatics](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pragmatics).

Comment: Nein, man braucht ja sowohl einen Waffenschein insgesamt, als auch einen Waffenbesitzschein für jede Waffe, nicht entweder/oder. Es muss also gesagt werden "Und der Besitz aller anderen Waffen ist ebenfalls strafbar, wenn man keinen Waffenschein oder keine Waffenbesitzkarte hat." Eine wie auch immer gedachte Klammerung löst das Problem gerade nicht.

Comment: Ja, das hätte gesagt werden müssen. Die Frage bezieht sich aber darauf, wie das zu verstehen ist, was tatsächlich gesagt wurde, nicht ob die Aussage korrekt war.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Ich war davon ausgegangen, dass die Sprecherintention ist, die sachlich korrekte Aussage zu machen, und dass nur die Grammatik ein bisschen holperig ist. Die Möglichkeit, dass die Sprechintention auf eine sachlich falsche Aussage hinauslaufen könnte, ist eine weitere Option, die ich gar nicht in Betracht gezogen hatte - und erst durch deine Antwort ist mir das klar geworden. Das macht natürlich alles noch komplizierter.